# Why  http post requests slowing down my Android app?

Tags: android

I am new to android and I have done an online chat app.  The problem is when I request 'http post' repeatedly to refresh my chat screen, the app hangs and I cannot perform any other operations.

Comment: use AsyncTask and every time check Internet Connectivity if u have not done it.

Comment: no,I have done in main tread itself.How to do it in Async task

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example

Comment: Async task is giving unknown host exception

Comment: Thanks all.Async task worked.But now, after using async task getcount method in list adapter is infinitely looping and no other methods in list adapter is working.

Answer (score 0):

Your Application freezes because you are performing a network operation within the Main Thread and you are blocking it.

This [Asynctask tutorial](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and this [blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html) will help you.

Comment: how to populate async task result to listview?

Comment: You can pass ListView in your AsyncTask. To get the result from AsyncTask, there is a method called onPostResult(Result) . so you can update your listview.

Note: Don't update listview from doInBackground().